# Get the text of the selected option using jQuery & ID start with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use to get the current selected option text using this javascript:-

```
var assignToApprovalusername = document.getElementById("OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice").value
```

but since the Id is relatively long,and this is a third party application which I can not modify its markup, so I tried to select the element by using start with as follow:-

```
var assignToApprovalusername = $('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"] option:selected').text();
```

but the second approach did not return the selected option text/

Comment: That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Execute the `.val()` function:**

```
$('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]').val();
```

That's similar to your approach.  However, probably the third-party app is generating, for instance, a hidden input with that Id.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  console.log($('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice'>
<option>One</option>
<option selected>two</option>
</select>
<br>
<button>Select</button>
```

Comment: `$('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]').val();` worked for me